# Quantities formatting problem

Tags: units

So I've developed this simple code

```
Mes /: MakeBoxes[Mes[mess_, error_, unit_], 
                 form : (StandardForm | TraditionalForm) : StandardForm
                ] := RowBox[{
                   MakeBoxes[NumberForm[Quantity[mess ± error, unit], {20, 2}], form]}]
```

in order to easily print things like this:

```
NumberForm[Quantity[1 ± 0.1, "picoFarads"], {20, 2}]
```

which give a nice output:

> ```
> (1.00 ± 0.10) pF
> ```

but using the `Mes` structure:

```
Mes[1, 0.1, "picoFarads"]
```

gives me:

> ```
> Quantity[1.00 ± 0.10,picoFarads]
> ```

On the other hand:

```
Mes[1, 0.1, "Farads"]
```

gives:

> ```
> (1.00 ± 0.10) F
> ```

I'm not sure what's going on but it seems to be connected with internet connection needed to interpret the units. How can I make `MakeBoxes` wait for the unit to get interpreted?

Answer (score 1):

You can let the unit be interpreted before calling the `MakeBoxes`:

```
Mes /: MakeBoxes[
         Mes[mess_, error_, unit_], 
         form : (StandardForm | TraditionalForm) : StandardForm] := 

          With[{u = QuantityUnit@ Quantity[1, unit]}, 
             RowBox[{
               MakeBoxes[NumberForm[Quantity[mess ± error, u], {20, 2}], form]
             }]
          ]
```

For your example:

```
Mes[1, 0.1, "picoFarads"]
```

[image]